# The name 'image' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, html, razor, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting a compile error from my HttpPost attribute in my controller that handles the upload of images. I have scoured the net trying to figure out if I am missing some sort of namespace, however, alas no where seems to have an answer. Here is my controller code as well as my view code.

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PhotoUpload(artisan.Models.UploadImageModel imageModel)
        {
            string path = @"D:\Temp\";

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (imageModel != null && imageModel.File != null)
                    image.SaveAs(path + imageModel.File.FileName);

                return RedirectToAction("Profile");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

My controller and views are in separate files in their respective folders.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PhotoUpload", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <label for="image">Upload Profile Image:</label>
        <input type="image" name="profilephoto" id="profilephoto" style="width: 100%;" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do. I guessing your trying to upload and save an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
image.SaveAs(path + imageModel.File.FileName);
```

try this

```
imageModel.File.SaveAs(path + imageModel.File.FileName);
```

Comment: that was the issue. Thanks a lot.